# Extension methods in typescript (system)

Tags: typescript, angular, prototype, typescript1.8

In my angular2 project I'm trying to extend the prototype of the *string* class using typescript.
This is my code:

```
interface String 
{
    startsWith(s:string);
    contains(s:string);
    containsOr(s1:string, s2:string);
}

String.prototype.startsWith = function (s:string):boolean {
    return this.indexOf (s) === 0;
}
String.prototype.contains = function (s:string):boolean {
    return this.indexOf(s) > 1;
}
String.prototype.containsOr = function (s1:string, s2:string):boolean {
    return this.indexOf(s1) > 1 || this.indexOf (s2) > 1;
}
```

With this code the project compiles (also the content assist of Visual Studio Code assists me) but at run-time I get a 'contains is not defined'.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

PS: this is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app/source/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**EDIT**

I noticed that importing the *js* file in *index.html* it works, but I don't like this approach.

```
<script src="app/source/utils/extensions.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you import your extensions? If you're using a module loader you're gonna have to check if the code you wrote is actually loaded.

Comment: Thanks Luka. What do you mean with import? I'm not exporting the class.
I updated the question with more details

Comment: Well in System.js you're going to need to tell the compiler where to find your code. It follows all of your imports and resolves them, loading the contents. That way you can avoid putting all the js files into you html.

Answer (score 25):

I was able to get it working with no TS errors (1.8.9), Angular2 (2.0.0-beta.12) errors, and working function call using the following template:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "system",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false
},
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "typings/main",
  "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Next, create (if one doesn't exist) a global.d.ts file local to your project:

**global.d.ts (local to project, not main TS file of same name)**

```
export {}

   declare global {
     interface String {
       calcWidth(): number;
     }
   }
```

**extensions.ts (entire file)**

```
export {}

//don't redefine if it's already there
if (!String.prototype.hasOwnProperty('calcWidth')) {
    String.prototype.calcWidth = function (): number {
      //width calculations go here, but for brevity just return length
      return this.length;
    }
}
```

Then in your whatever your first System.import(*filename*) is (mine is main.ts). Just use once:

```
import './extensions'  //or whatever path is appropriate
... 
...
```

Now, throughout your app you can use your interface:

```
var testString = 'fun test';
console.log(testString.calcWidth());
```

Produces console output:

```
8
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of importing the code in html just put this at the top of your code:

```
import './utils/extensions';
```

Just replace it with your path to the file.

Here are some more resources on modules and imports:

[TypeScript docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md)

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import)

Comment: In this way I get the following error: *http://localhost:2068/app/source/utils/extensions.js detected as register but didn't execute.(…)*

Comment: Can you try exporting `String` in your `extensions.ts`? :)

Comment: Adding the *export* work before *interface* I get a compile error *error TS2339: Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'String'.
app/source/utils/extensions.ts(15,18): error TS2339: Property 'containsOr' does not exist on type 'String'.*

The strange thing is that the error is related to contains() and containsOr, and not to startsWith() >.<

Comment: That is certainly strange! What happens if you instead write `export String` at the end of your file?

Comment: The compiler gives me *Declaration or statement expected*. I'm going crazy

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a mess, sorry I've not been of more help so far, maybe putting in the html wasn't such a bad idea after all. :/