# Extension for window.Node in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add a new method to window.Node

```
interface Node {
    myMethod(selector: any): any
}

Node.prototype.myMethod = (selector) => {
   //some code
}
```

and use it in my code, but this method is not defined. As I can understand after running "ionic serve" this code is not included in the build version.

My tsconfig.json file

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
},
"files": [
    "src/app/customextensions/extensions.ts" //file with my new method
],
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
],
"compileOnSave": false,
"atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
}
```

I've tried to add

```
/// <reference path="customextensions/extensions.ts" />
```

to my app.component.ts but it still doesn't work.

Update:
[Extension methods in typescript (system)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432983/extension-methods-in-typescript-system?rq=1) - the Paul's solution solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not generate any code for interfaces. Go to typescript playground and check. [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/][1]

In your extensions.ts do:

```
export interface Node {
   myMethod(selector: any): any
}
export const MyNode : Node = {
  myMethod(selector: any): any { 
    // put a function body here 
 }
}
```

and in you code you can import MyNode and call method on it

```
import {MyNode} from 'app/customextensions/extensions';

MyNode.myMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't exactly what I want. E.g. in vanilla JS I can write Node.prototype.myMethod = () => {}; and then, somewhere in my app I can call this method for html node, e.g. document.body.myMethod(). Are there some ways to do the same in typescript?