# ngxs: augment the Store class

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am using Ngxs Store in an angular application. I would like to add some convenience methods to the store. E.g.

```js
// new store getter
get order(): Order {
  this.selectSnapshot((appState: AppState) => appState.order);
}

// usage in a service 
class MyService {

  constructor(store: Store) {
    // store instance has the extra getter
    console.log(store.order) 
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, although I think it's less maintainable than standard tools, that ngxs provides.

You could create separate .ts file and let typescript merge interfaces on the fly -> [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432983/extension-methods-in-typescript-system)

But you actually rarely need selectSnapshot method. **You should use selectors with observables most of the time.**

```
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  @Select(AppState.orders) orders$: Observable<Order[]>;
}
```

`selectSnapshot` method is useful for cases where you can't use observable.
Or if you really need to use `selectSnapshot` and want to provide some helper methods you could create angular service, inject the store and put common convenience methods in there.